# React Native Scheduled Local Notifications showing scheduled time instead of current time in notification tray

Tags: react-native, scheduler, localnotification, react-native-push-notification

I have scheduled a local notification by adding 1 day as scheduled date. When receiving notification it shows notification arrival date as 1 day ago which is the scheduler added date, instead of current time as(now). Anyway to fix this?

Comment: I'm using **react-native-push-notification** library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `buildAndroidNotification` function has attribute `when` attribute as follows,

`when: new Date().getTime()`

instead of current date object it needed to pass scheduled date's time value,
if using moment.js

```
 let timeStampMoment = moment(scheduleDate, "MM-DD-YYYY Z").valueOf();
```

and set,

```
  when: timeStampMoment
```